# How to write tests for transferring ERC20 token from contract

Tags: solidity, hardhat

I can transfer ERC20 token from contract to normal account, but I can't find a way to write tests for it. This is what I tried (I'm using Hardhat):

```js
// treasury is a contract
await dai.connect(treasury.signer).approve(account2.address, 10);
await treasury.connect(account2).withdraw(10, dai.address);
```

do anyone know how to do it?

Comment: Your question is not super clear. By "I can't find a way to write tests for it" do you mean you don't know how to transfer ERC20 tokens inside of a hardhat test or something else?

Comment: I want to call `approve` to let the contract can transfer ERC20 token from contract to user's wallet.

Comment: Could you provide the error you get when using the above code? Or do you mean you don't know how to write a test after enacting this transfer to make sure that it worked?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.